# Find the context under which an InfoPath form is running

Tags: c#, infopath

In InfoPath code behind is there a way to find the context under which the form is running. So we're looking at either the InfoPath client itself or whether it's running under InfoPath Forms Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to your `FormEvents_Loading` method. This checks whether the form is browser-based or not:

```
if (this.Application.Environment.IsBrowser) 
{ 
}
```